# Calculating Contribution in power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have the following columns in my table

- date
- category
- sales

i display the following columns in a power bi table with a date filter

- category
- Sales(Sum)

How do i calculate contribution ?

- Category
- Sales(Sum)
- Contribution

Comment: Any supplemental information would be helpful. Are  you talking about contribution margin or contribution margin ration? If so you need another column for expenses?

Comment: It would be very helpful; for you to edit you question, adding tables (not image) of sample input data and corresponding output data.